# How to implement a site wide class and functions that can be called from anywhere in a Zend Framework Application?

Tags: zend-framework

I know there are view controllers and action controllers. I think that view helpers can be used from views and action helpers used from actions in controllers.

I need a class that at bootstrap or wherever, it initializes a number of configuration options, arrays for things like convert month numbers to their names and role numbers to their names.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a model and use it anywhere you like by instantiating it and calling its helper methods. All model files are auto loaded whenever you call them.

Have a model Constants.php:

```
<?php

class Constants {

    public static function convertMonth($month) {
        doLogic();
        return $something;
    }
}
?>
```

In your controller or view:

```
Constants::convertMonth(12);
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'Constants' not found`, I called it from a form file

Comment: you should place the Constants.php in your `models` directory.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I needed to call the class `class Model_Constants` as I have used the following in the resourceloader: `'model' => array
     (
      'path' => 'models/',
      'namespace' => 'Model_'
     ),` I don't know why I did that? Would you consider that a good practice.

Comment: if you have multiple namespaces for your models, I would recommend that. Otherwise, you don't need a namespace. Just the model name is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a Resource Plugin and then add it to yout bootstrap class.

Answer (score 1):

The Constants class or Resource approaches both work nicely.  However, I recently had to undo/upgrade a Constants class based solution to meet new requirements, so you might want to consider your future plans before going down those paths.

Specifically, if you ever intend to support multiple languages, or even different words for the constants in different contexts, check out [Zend_Translate API docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html), [Zend_Translate example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.using.html), or [this blog post](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/22/localize-your-site-in-3-easy-steps/).